# DB2 append backups into one unique db

Tags: db2, append, backup, restore, db2-luw

I am using the restore db to import backup into a test environment database that works fine, but I need to extend this import process to several backups from several dates into a unique test environment db... What is the command to append backups into a unique database...

thanks
Phil

Comment: What type of backups are you using? What Db2 platform and version? What command have you used for your initial restore?

Comment: Offline backups , BD2 Windows version 9.7.200 , I create a script with the following command : db2 restore db [XXXX] from [YYYY] taken at [zzzzzzzzzz] redirect generate script XYZ.clp       and then run the script using command : db2 -tvf XYZ.clp

Comment: And each offline backup is a FULL backup, right?

Comment: yes each offline backup is a full database backup .... Ideally only some data tables should be imported in the main unique database.

Comment: You cannot use Db2-LUW offline FULL backup/Restore to achieve what you appear to want. Instead, you seem to want a method to copy (synch, replicate) __some__ content (some tables) from a production database into a dev/test database.   Analyse your requirement more carefully to better express what you really want to do.

Comment: Not exactly...I no have access to the production database, I get only full offline database backup files from several time date (2 weeks of production) that I need to restore in a test database for analysis... example 4 backups files of 2 weeks of data = 2 months of data ....

Comment: As mentioned, you __cannot__ combine two full offline Db2-backups into one database. But you __can__ restore each full offline backup into its own discrete database (i.e. 2 separate databases , each with different content).

Answer (score 0):

You write *"I get only full offline database backup files from several time date (2 weeks of production) that I need to restore in a test database for analysis... example 4 backups files of 2 weeks of data = 2 months of data* ...."

and you also write *"What is the command to append backups into a unique database..."*

While there is no explicit method for full-offline-backup images to be combined for Db2-LUW, there's always another way to get what you need...given the right skills and tools.

IF you have a FULL backup image, it can either be restored to a new database, or it can fully overwrite an existing database. If you have 4 FULL backup images, each can be restored either into a (uniquely named) database (or overwrite 4 existing databases).

You can also restore specific tablespaces from a backup image, if properly configured. Some sites have designed discrete tablespaces for specific time periods (one per day/week/month) to help with such activities. Some sites have designed their tables to be range partitioned (with each time period having its own partition (and sometimes dedicated tablespaces also), and this makes subsequent merging of content more easy with the right skills.

If you are competent with scripting, you can restore the first (earliest) image, export the relevant table contents to flat-files,  restore the next backup image and export the relevant tables to new flat-files (repeat as needed), then load these flat-files into a table for analysis. If your database size is small then this can be considered a keep-it-simple approach.

You can also do clever things with federation if you restore to discrete databases.

Separately purchasable tools exist to let you extract selected content from a backup image (which can then be loaded into a Db2 database), without needing to do a restore action.  These are not included with the Db2 product. So you could extract specific table contents from a backup image if you pay for the right tools and learn how to use them. Speak with your IBM Salesperson. Such tools may require currently supported versions of Db2 however.